# ssrs 2008r2 calculate between two datasets

Tags: reporting-services

In my report currently there are two tables, each binding to a dataset

```
    table 1 (dataset 1):

    date1, date2 (column group)

    value1, value2 



    table 2 (dataset 2):

    date1, date2 (column group)

    value3, value4
```

date1, date2 in each table have the same values. What I want to achieve:

in table 2 add one more row, so it will looks like this:

```
    table 2 (dataset 2):

    date1, date2 (column group)

    value3, value4

    value1/value3, value2/value4
```

As you can see, value1 and value2 are from table 1(dataset 1), is there anyway to achieve this? I know I can do this in SQL but would like to know if this achievable in SSRS?

Comment: You can try using `Lookup` function in `Common Functions >> Miscellaneous` to get the Dataset2 values.

Comment: Thanks. I used sql at last. would rather to use something already familiar with. If you can post detailed solution using SSRS I will give it a try and pick as answer if it works.

Comment: posted example of using Lookup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example to use the lookup ..

Using two datasets ..

[image]

The link between the two data set is Dataset1.id = Dataset2.DSid

As to your description to divide value from Dataset1 with value from Dataset2.

In the table detail, use expression ..

```
=Fields!totalhold.Value / Lookup(Fields!id.Value, Fields!DSid.Value, Fields!totalh.Value, "DataSet2")
```